# Wine has stopped working

Tags: wine, gui

All I can do is browse the c: drive. I removed and reinstalled wine and it still won't open. What can I do? (I am trying to open it in the GUI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wine configuration is located not in the system-wide, but in the user dir (/home/user/.wine or simply in ~/.wine). You can backup this folder and run again the wine, this will create a new folder with all your configuration, **including the wine's C:**.

To simply delete this folder (including the drive_c) you can execute:

```
 rm -rf ~/.wine
```

To backup:

```
 mv ~/.wine ~/.wine.bak
```

Your old windows drive_c will be in ~/.wine.bak/drive_c

Next, you can reinstall your wine apps.